# How to run a C program with python Popen?

Tags: python

I have to run a C program by my Python script. I have already compiled the C program and I need to call it from Python to execute it.

I've used the subprocess.Popen class to do so, but I'm getting the following issue: 'No such file or directory': /path/to/my/bin/./mybin.
Does anyone know what I'am doing wrong?
Thank you in advance

```
   import subprocess
   subprocess.Popen("/path/to/my/bin/./mybin")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python)

Comment: Which path is it, `/path/to/my/bin/./mybin` or `/path/to/my/bin/.mybin` ?

Comment: @khelwood ./mybin

Comment: Why do you have the single dot there? Seems completely pointless. Change it to this instead: `/path/to/my/bin/mybin`

Comment: @klutt I've edited it

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that the file simply does not exist.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen("/path/to/my/bin/mybin")` or `subprocess.Popen("./mybin")`. You could also just use `subprocess.run` with the same argument, you don't need Popen here.